# Running c# code on button click in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page with a button on it. When the user clicks on a button, i have to run some c# code in a seperate .cs file. What is the way to do this? Currently i have a way of using form.action to forward the request to another aspx page but is there a way to run c # code upon a button press?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using a button click event handler on the same page?

Comment: can you create partial classes ?

Comment: @Oded, I wouldn't be surprised if the logic is located in another handler on another aspx page and in fact, what he needs to do, is move that logic to another function that can be called from more than one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event handlers

Ex:

```
<asp:Button id="b1" runat="server" OnClick="b1_OnClick"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void b1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //call your .cs file code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop your .cs file into an `App_Code` directory and ought to be able to call accessible methods within that code without needing to reference an external assembly.

Answer (score 0):

### Sample Code using partial class

### Physical File Name - abc.cs

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.ID = "Button" + i;
        b.Text = "Button" + i;
        b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
        form1.Controls.Add(b);
    }

}
```

---

### Physical File Name - abc1.cs

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished in below way:

### In ASPX file:

```
<asp:Button id="btnTarget" runat="server" Text="Target" OnClick="btnTarget_OnClick"/>
```

### In code behind (.cs) file:

```
//First put the namespace of your target class in using block

protected void btnTarget_OnClick(object sender, EventArges e)
{
    //Target.NameSpace.TargetClass target = new Target.NameSpace.TargetClass(); // without using namespace in using blcok
    TargetClass target = new TargetClass(); // you can use direct Namespece here
    target.TargetMethod();
}
```

### Update:

Put your code of `TargetClass` in App_Code folder which will be available around the application, the `TargetClass` should be `public` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET works in an event-driven model. Whatever the actions performed by an user whether it is a button click or some other which can be listened by an event-handler that will be located in the code-behind of the aspx page.

You can put all the code in the event-handler or you can call other class methods from the event-handler and do whatever you want.